# Как удалить записи из бд сделанные сегодня(00:00>)?

Tags: php, mysql

Как удалить записи из бд сделанные сегодня? То бишь после 00:00

Comment: А можно сделать сегодня до 00:00?

Comment: @Mike разве это не удалит все записи ДО сегодня?))

Comment: `delete from table where date_column>curdate()`  @АлексейШиманский УПС .... знак перепутал :)

Answer (score -1):

Определяем timestamp начала дня.

```
$cur_date = mktime(0,0,0);
```

Далее выполняем SQL-запрос:

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE date_col>='$cur_date';
```